# Overpass get Street in City

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I'm trying to get all the nodes of one street in a district in Berlin.

I've written the following expression, but it returns all `Holteistraße` in Germany. Anyone know how I would write a correct syntax?

```
[out:json];

(
area["Berlin, Friedrichshain"];
way[highway][name="Holteistraße"];
);

out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to overpass-turbo.eu and enter the following the wizard popup:

```
highway=* and name=Holteistraße in Berlin
```

This will create the following query, which includes `(area.searchArea)` as a reference to the previously found area. Also, the area needs to match exactly the existing tagging of a way or relation. `area["Berlin, Friedrichshain"];` would simply try to find a way/relation with the **key** "Berlin, Friedrichshain". Obviously, no such object exists.

```
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“highway=* and name=Holteistraße in Berlin”
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// fetch area “Berlin” to search in
{{geocodeArea:Berlin}}->.searchArea;
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “highway=* and name="Holteistraße"”
  node["highway"]["name"="Holteistraße"](area.searchArea);
  way["highway"]["name"="Holteistraße"](area.searchArea);
  relation["highway"]["name"="Holteistraße"](area.searchArea);
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped quite a bit. Do you know how I can restrict the search to a district? Holteistraße is fine, but some streets appear twice in Berlin.
My second question would be if you know how I can make an api call for 500 different streets? (I'm new to this)
Thank you!

Comment: You need to replace {{geocodeArea:Berlin}}->.searchArea by something like area[boundary=administrative][admin_level=??][name="xyz"] -> .searchArea; see  https://wambachers-osm.website/boundaries/ for some ideas. For the second one, please ask a new question.